# Translating Polar Functions

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

How do I rewrite a polar function (expressed in a polar coordinate system $r = F(\theta)$ so the entire curve is shifted right or left $h$ units and up or down $k$ units?

Comment: In what coordinate system is the curve shifted?

Comment: If you want to shift wrt to, e.g, cartesian coordinates, you may be out of luck and not be able to write the curve in that form again. Consider, as an example, a circle of radius one, which you shift two units in any direction.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for taking the time to address my question.  My goal is to have the function rewritten with respect to the polar system so that $r$ values are mapped to $\theta$ values, but to shift the curve as if the Pole were at $(p_x, p_y)$ instead of $(0, 0)$.  Although I suppose I could have a process where the function were rewitten as if the Pole were at $(r_p, \theta_p)$ with $\theta_p=\arctan{\frac{p_y}{p_x}}$ and $r_p=\sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2}$.

I took the previous suggestion and tried focusing on the specific case of a circle and after some further messing around I was able to get this to work for a polar circle function, rewriting $r = a$ (where $a$ is the radius) as $$r = r_p \cos(\theta - \theta_p) + \sqrt{a^2 - r_p^2 \sin(\theta - \theta_p)^2}$$
leading to 
$$r = \sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2} \cos\left(\theta - \arctan\frac{p_y}{p_x}\right) + \sqrt{a^2 - (p_x^2 + p_y^2) \sin \left(\theta - \arctan\frac{p_y}{p_x}\right)^2}.$$
This gave me a function with terms containing constants $p_x, p_y$ that I could adjust to make a Cartesian like translation of a circle rendered in the polar plane.  But when I tried to reproduce this process for something like a Leminscate, $r = \pm \sqrt{a^2 \cos(n \theta)}$, I got stuck again and kept distorting the curve.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to get $r=F(\theta)$ in parametric equations, and then apply $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$.

If you move the function to right in $\Delta x$ and to up in $\Delta y$, then
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{new}(\theta)=r\cos(\theta)-\Delta x\\
y_{new}(\theta)=r\sin(\theta)-\Delta y
\end{cases}
$$
Then $r_{new}$ can be expressed as
$$
r_{new}=\sqrt{(r\cos(\theta)-\Delta x)^2+(r\sin(\theta)-\Delta y)^2}
$$

Comment: If you move the function to right, $\theta$ will be different. The $\theta$ in your formula $r_{new}=\sqrt{(r\cos(\theta)-\Delta x)^2+(r\sin(\theta)-\Delta y)^2}$ is the old $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the final form to be Polar you could achieve the result by translating the whole equation into Cartesian and then subtracting $h$ and $k$ from all occurrences of $x$ and $y$. For instance:

Your circle $r=\alpha$ becomes $\sqrt{\left(x-h\right)^2+\left(y-k\right)^2}=\alpha$.

In the case of a Spiral $r=\theta$ becomes  $\sqrt{\left(x-h\right)^2+\left(y-k\right)^2}=\arctan\left(\frac{y-k}{x-h}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are translating the pole by $\Delta x$ + $\Delta y$, it's simply:

$$
r_{new}= r + \Delta x.\cos(\theta) + \Delta y.\sin(\theta)
$$