# Find the area between the following curves and their asymptotes.

Tags: integration, area, polar-coordinates

The curve is given by the polar equation  $ r = a( \sec \theta + \cos \theta) $
At $\theta = \pi /2, r$ goes to infinity, so asymptotes should be at $\theta = \pi /2$
To find the area I integrated $2$ $ \frac{a^{2}(\sec \theta + \cos \theta)^{2}}{2} $ ($= r^{2}/2  \times 2$, since curve is symmetric about $x$ axis) with respect to $\theta$ from $0$ to infinity and got infinity.

But answer is given $5 \pi a^{2}/2$
Where did I go wrong$?$

Comment: Why do you integrate $r^2$? Explain what is your area element

Comment: I think you want to integrate from 0 to $\pi/2$ (not to infinity).

Comment: You did not find the polar equation of the asymptote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given the curve
$$ r = a( \sec \theta + \cos \theta) \tag{1}$$
but we are not given the asymptote.

It is clearly a vertical asymptote of the form $x=$constant, but what is the constant?

So what is happening to $x=r\cos\theta$ as $\theta\to\frac{\pi}{2}$?

We can find this out by multiplying equation (1) by $\cos\theta$ to obtain

$$ r\cos\theta = a( 1 + \cos^2 \theta) $$

Since $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ we see that as $\theta\to\frac{\pi}{2}$, $r\cos\theta\to a$.

So the vertical asymptote of the curve is $x=a$.

In polar coordinates this is $r\cos\theta=a$

So $r=a\sec\theta$ is the polar equation of the asymptote of the function.

So the area between the function and its asymptote can be found by the following:

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} a^2(\sec\theta+\cos\theta)^2-a^2\sec^2\theta\,d\theta $$

We shall see that $\dfrac{5\pi a^2}{2}$ is **not** the correct answer.

> \begin{eqnarray}
>   \int_0^{\pi/2} a^2(\sec\theta+\cos\theta)^2-a^2\sec^2\theta\,d\theta&=&
>   a^2\int_0^{\pi/2}2+\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
>   &=&a^2\int_0^{\pi/2}2+\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}\,d\theta\\
>   &=&a^2\left[\frac{5}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2\theta)\right]_0^{\pi/2}\\
>   &=&\frac{5\pi a^2}{4}
>   \end{eqnarray}

Comment: Since the curve is symmetric about x axis, so area should be multiplied by 2, I think.

Comment: Yes, it has been multiplied by two, cancelling the 2 in the denominator of the integrand.  $2\int \frac{f^2(\theta)}{2}\,d\theta=\int f^2(\theta)\,d\theta$.

Comment: Oh, yes I got it. Thanks.

Comment: 'It is clearly a vertical asymptote of the form =constant' , sir , i am new to polar equations and curve tracing ,how is the asymptote vertical ?

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh Because $y=r\sin\theta=a(\tan\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta)\to\infty$ as $\theta\to\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ whereas $x=r\cos\theta=a(1+\cos^2\theta)$ approaches a constant.

Answer (score 1):

(1) calculating areas made by polar plots in [polar coordinates](https://mathinsight.org/polar_coordinates_mapping) is done with the help of [a special integration formula](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Polar_Integration).

(2) polar coordinates transformation (moving to another origin) is needed, because the area is not exactly measured from the origin like it's usually calculated as in the explanations. See [this](https://pritschet.me/wiki/physics/linear-translation-polar-coordinates/) and [this also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446733/translating-polar-functions).

Transform [the polar equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20(1%2Fcos(x)%2Bcos(x)),%20x%20%3D%20-pi%2F2%20..pi%2F2) ($-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$) $$r = a \cdot (\sec(\theta)+\cos(\theta)) $$ to the following ***equivalent*** [parametric equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(1%2Bcos%5E2(t),%20tan(t)%2Bcos(t)*sin(t)),%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi%2F2) using $x=r \cdot \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r \cdot\sin(\theta)$  $$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r \cdot \cos(\theta) \\ r \cdot \sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (a\cdot (\sec(\theta)+\cos(\theta)) ) \cdot \cos(\theta) \\ (a\cdot (\sec(\theta)+\cos(\theta))) \cdot \sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix} = a \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1+\cos^2(\theta) \\ \tan(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$

Now move the $x$-koordinates of the points on the curve by an amount of $a$ to the left. When $\theta = 0$ or when you're on the $x$-axis, you want that point on the curve lying on the $x$-axis to be at $x = a$ and not at $x = 2a$. So, you subract an $a$ from all the $x$-koordinates or you take $x-a$. The [shifted curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(cos%5E2(t),%20tan(t)%2Bcos(t)*sin(t)),%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi%2F2) by $a$ to the left is:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = a \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \cos^2(\theta) \\ \tan(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$

We [could](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(cos%5E2(t)cos(%202%20t)%2Bcos%5E2(t)sec%5E2(t),t,-pi%2F2,pi%2F2)) directly [calculate the area for this parametric curve](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx) (Notice the change of the variables $x$ and $y$ for our purposes. This is like rotating the coordinate system or exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$, because this given formula in these notes calculates the area between the parametric curve and the $x$-axis and we want to calculate the are between the parametric curve and the $y$-axis):

$$   
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(\theta)\frac{d y(\theta)}{d \theta} d\theta 
= 
a^2 \cdot \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\theta) \cos( 2 \theta)+\cos^2(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)  d\theta 
=
\frac{5a^2\pi}{4} 
$$